# WAV file not in sync with source MP3 file

Tags: mp3, wav

I am using NAudio and Adobe Media Encoder (separately) to convert a 2-hour MP3 file into a WAV file.

The resulting WAV file is not in sync with the source MP3 file:

MP3 second #996 = WAV second #1000

MP3 second #1991 = WAV second #2000

The Google Speech API requires a WAV file to create a time-coded transcript, but the time codes are then not accurate for the MP3 file (which is a podcast).

I have to use MP3 as the source format, since that is what all the podcasts use.

How can I create a WAV file that is in sync with the source MP3 file?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it's not-in-sync?  The codec for playing back the MP3 and the codec for converting it to WAV are the same thing.  Or at least, even if they are different implementations, should deterministically have identical output.

I suspect that the times are the same, but that you are seeking into the MP3 file when previewing the audio.

MP3 files don't have timestamps.  You can't seek into them reliably without decoding up to the seek point first.  Most players estimate where in the file to start playback based on the byte length of the file and estimated overall bitrate based on the first couple frames.  For CBR, this can be accurate within a half second or so.  For VBR, it can be off by enormous amounts.

This is one of the reasons raw MP3 is bad for anything other than streaming.  MP3 can be used within other container formats, such as Matroska, which help fix this problem.  Unfortunately, podcasters don't do this.

Basically, there is no real solution to your problem, but it also may not be a problem if the listener simply plays back the podcast in real time, without skipping around.

Comment: I know its out of sync because the audio that occurs on the MP3 file at second #1991 does not occur in the WAV file until second #2000. Therefore, the timestamps which Google Speech API created from the WAV file do not align with the MP3 file on the podcast.

Comment: @Tester How do you get to second 1,991 in your MP3 file?  Did you use your audio player to skip ahead, or did you let it play all the way through to that point?

Comment: To play from a specific time, I set the 'currentTime' property of the audio object (in javascript): https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp

Comment: Yes, in that case your seeking isn't accurate, and would explain the problem.

Comment: The currentTime property is very accurate. If you don't know what you're talking about, then don't post answers.

Comment: @Tester Heh, sure.  I don't need to qualify my knowledge on the topic.  It's not my problem that you can't solve yours.  I was just trying to be helpful.  I suggest you re-read what I wrote, create some simple tests to prove it to yourself, and if you still don't believe me, spend some time with a hex editor looking for the in-stream timestamps you believe are present.

Comment: There are no "in-stream timestamps". The timestamps are added to the transcript that is generated by the Google Speech API from the WAV file. Those timestamps (in the transcript) are not in sync with the MP3.

Comment: @Tester Your MP3 stream has no timestamps in it.  You cannot seek it accurately without decoding the whole thing.  Seeking an MP3 has non-deterministic results, depending on factors such as whether or not the decoder has decoded up to the seek point, the CBR/VBR nature of the stream, the player's algorithm, delivery mechanism of the stream (HTTP with range request capability or no?), and probably other factors.  I don't know how to make this clearer to you, so this will be my last comment on the issue.